# Why is the Grails-Gradle plugin necessary?

Tags: grails, gradle

I am building my first Grails app and would like the build to be managed by Gradle. I see that there is a [Grails-Gradle plugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin) and many online searches indicate that it is not possible to build a Grails app using Gradle without this plugin.

My question is: **why?** Why (specifically) is this plugin necessary in order for Gradle to be able to build a Grails app? What functionality does this plugin provide that is otherwise missing?

Comment: You could have asked the same question for [**Groovy plugin**](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html) and above all the [**Java plugin**](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you think it's impossible to build a Grails app without the plugin. It's possible to issue commands to the grails shell from Gradle without the plugin, but it's not very clean.

That's what this plugin does. It cleans up that process, and makes it much Groovier with a DSL. It also makes your Gradle script more portable to other projects and persons.

If you browse the [source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-gradle-plugin/tree/master/src/main/groovy/org/grails/gradle/plugin) you will see all the inner workings of the plugin and realize what it's setting up in your Gradle script. What it offers is a lot of access to Grails in a very standard and portable manner.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Moore (+1) - but a few things. For one, are you saying that the plugin adds a DSL **on top** of Gradle? Or are you just saying that Gradle itself is a Groovy DSL? And two, what's to stop me from just trying to build my grails app with "raw" Gradle? Thanks again!

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from making your Gradle script do whatever you want. When I say DSL I mean it adds a DSL into Gradle for dealing with Grails builds.